# How to hide non-static methods in struct suggestions provided by rust-analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, ide, rust-analyzer

I'm using rust-analyzer 0.3.193-nightly with VSCode 1.45.1, Windows 10 x64.

On a struct, when I type `::`, I'd like to see the static methods only. Non-static methods are also showing up in suggestion list.

I the example below, I would *not* like to see `calc_num` appear in suggestions, since it's a non-static method:

[image: VSCode editor showing suggestions]

Is there a way to hide `calc_num` from the suggestions, in the example above? I searched rust-analyzer options and I found nothing.

Comment: You may or may not be aware, but methods _are_ associated functions (Rust doesn't use the term "static" for these). That means you can do things like `.map(Foo::calc_num)`

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm aware that method *are* associated functions in Rust. Actually, RLS with VSCode does exactly what I'm trying here. I'm trying to move away from RLS because it's really buggy.

Comment: Amusingly, I'd say that it not showing the methods is one of the bugs!

Comment: @Shepmaster You made me laugh really loud on this one. Do you recommend me using rust-analyzer over RLS?

Comment: I think that rust-analyzer is better in almost all ways than RLS, yes. I think your request is a reasonable one, as it's a matter of how useful the autocomplete set is to you.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you. I just [opened an issue](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/4731) in rust-analyzer repo.